# Mysql overlap vs distance--which is faster?

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, geolocation

I'm trying to find rows which are within ____meters from the given point.

THis can be done via distance  or overlap.

WHat is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use distance